# Interactive 3D Connect dots

Tags: graphics, manipulate, interactive

I have some 2d slices of a 3d model - These are comprised of points and lines. I want to connect them using something like nearest neighbors, but some of the points in each 2D slice are too far apart for that to completely work out.

What I'd like to do, is to display each of the 2d slices in a 3d model, and allow the user to 'pick' pairs of points to draw a line connecting them together. Then, I'd like to take that pick connection and use it to update the computer's best guess as to how to connect the 2 slices in parallel.

What I don't know how to do is put together the interactive part, which is composed of two parts: the user clicking in the model (and being able to rotate and zoom) and then having those calculations being dynamically fed to a function which recomputes the best guess.

Much thanks for any references or actual code examples for how to do this.

Edit:

A typical format for the dataset is

```
dataset = {{{1, 2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 4}},
  {{2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 5, 4}}}
```

And a simple render would be:

```
renderSlices[list_] := 
 Graphics3D[
  Flatten[MapIndexed[
    Function[{sheet, z}, 
     MapIndexed[
      Function[{line, 
        lineIndex}, {RGBColor[Mod[N[Exp[lineIndex]], 1][[1]], 0.6, 
         0.3], Line @@ {MapIndexed[
           Function[{point, y}, {point, y[[1]], z[[1]]}], line]}}], 
      sheet]], list]]]
```

You can call:

```
renderSlices[dataset]
```

to see the results.

One thing to note is that there are some points between these lines which kind of match. However, I would like to be able to click between them and use that to inform how I guess the correspondence.

This looks like:

[image: Graph of 3 slices with 2 lines per slice]

(I'm using dark mode)

Comment: Can you provide a small sample dataset and possibly code to draw non-interactive versions of the plot or else some kind of picture or diagram showing what you’re thinking? I think I sort of understand from the description, but I’m not certain.

Comment: Edited with more information.